# Unable to uninstall an android app : Getting a crash message

Tags: android, crash, apk, uninstallation

i created an android app using Android Studio 3.1, and then installed it on a Samsung Galaxy S6 running on Android 7.0 Nougat. The problem is that i can no longer uninstall the app from my phone:

When i try to uninstall the app, i have an crash message stating that "The uninstalling program kit has crashed" ... I tried reinstalling the app from android studio, didn't work, and when i try to reinstall it using an apk, i get the same crash message.

I will be thankful if you can help me out

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue with your device settings. Another approach to uninstall the program is through `adb command`. Use following command:

```
adb uninstall <you-package-name>
```

Comment: I'm new to android programming, where can i execute this command?